# Strange LWUIT Dialog behaviour while using Dialog.showPacked() with BorderLayout.CENTRE positioning

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-dialog

I am using LWUIT for series 40 for making my J2ME app and I have noticed a strange behavior of the LWUIT-Dialog while using the showPacked() method, the dialog being positioned with BorderLayout.CENTER.

This happens especially in touch phones.

I have attached an image in order to describe my situation.

[image: Image link]

Initially the dialog appears as shown in the first part of the image.However,it expands in the next few seconds to become like the one shown in the second part of the image.

Future calls to display the dialog using showPacked appears like the third one.I am clueless as to why this is happening.I want my dialog to appear like the one shown in the first half of the image all the time.Where have I gone wrong?

Note : The content of the Dialog is a an animated label.

Comment: You can give code that you implement?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the guys did there but I'm guessing they reflow the UI too aggressively. Try setting `Dialog.setAutoAdjustDialogSize(false)` and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I did what you told me to do, now the dialog doesn't re size on the first attempt.But it appears like the second and the third stage in the subsequent calls.

And all I have done is that create a label with an image.Animated it by following (http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/11/20/animation-and-transition-with-lwuit.html) this post in lwuit blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the title and background et al. with the code below, it makes only your animated GIF show with the dimmed dialog background :

```
setTitle(" ");
setUIID("Null");
setDialogUIID("Null");
getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
getSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
getDialogStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
```